# ClassNotFoundException when launching junit tests in Eclipse 2019-12 on Windows when using Java 9+

Tags: eclipse

Having upgraded to eclipse 2019-12, I can no longer run *some* of my junit tests. The specific symptoms I get are that I just get the following message in the console view:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner
```

This doesn't apply to all my projects only some of them.

Attempting to simplify this to a small example fails, suggesting that it's to do with the complexity of the project. I can take a project for which this fails, remove all of the actual code, put a simple "no-op" test case in leaving the classpath the same, and it still fails, so it's not related to the content of the tests, but suggests there's something in the classpath that's causing the problem. Attempting to simplify the classpath to find the offending library or project leads to inconsistent results. I think I find the offending library, a library such that if I remove it things work and I put it back and they fail, but then I try again and I get different results.

Very confusing.

I'm documenting this in case others find the same thing, the solution is below.

Answer (score 2):

After much investigation, it turns out that this appears to be a bug in eclipse.

When the classpath gets too long, and when launching java 9+ eclipse will generate the classpath in an argument file, passing the name of that file on the java command line.

In eclipse 2019-12 the classpath argument string in that file is surrounded by quotes. Unfortunately this means that the backslashes within the classpath are interpretted as escape characters causing the classpath to be misunderpretted.

Eclipse 2019-09 doesn't appear to generate the quotes round the classpath in the argument file, so the problem doesn't occur.

The problem will only occur when launching java 9+, since that's when support for argument files were introduced. The problem will only occur on Windows, since on Linux/mac platforms the classpath will have forward slash separators in and not backslash.

This isn't restricted to launching junit, this will be a problem for any launch, I happened to be seeing this with a junit launch.

Documenting this here in the hope that it might help others solve the issue quicker.

Eclipse issue reference is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=559147